# Why am I getting this error in MCBE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I keep getting an error that says you need to authenticate to Microsoft services. I'm on Nintendo switch. this happens whenever I try to go on a server. I've tried signing out of my Microsoft account and I've tried google.

This only happens when I'm at home. It won't do it at a friend's house.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one thing I believe you could do is get a vpn, as your ip might be blocked for some reason, or simply create a new minecraft account. And I do know nintendo needs some sort of subscription to be able to play minecraft online (I think), I don't know if that's the problem? As of now there is no real answer for this, but thats all I can think of for now. Tell me if any of these work, and if you have any questions.

Comment: Also i'm not sure the vpn will work, but its worth a shot.

Comment: ok thx for the help

Comment: Oh it is a ip related problem, I see, then the VPN will definitely work.

Comment: do you know how to add the VPN to a switch or something?

Comment: also how much would a VPN cost?

Comment: You can find some for free, but the cost for a payed one is around $5 a month I believe.

Comment: anyone know how to add a vpn to a switch????

Comment: @gizmo if you don't even know if it works yet, i recommend you don't mark it as accepted. How do you even know it's an ip problem? You haven't checked it. To be frank this answer seems like a shot - no not a shot a shotgun in the dark.

Comment: @Penguin i have tried to reset my router, and it worked for a day and then the error popped up the next day

Comment: i just dont got the time to keep resetting the router

Comment: You said it works at your friends house but when you go to your house it doesn't, so that means it's almost 100% an ip problem.

Comment: Also, you use an vpn on your router, not your device, because your device connects to your router and then though to the vpn, so you will need to install some sort of vpn compatible with your router and then connect to a server in your area that the vpn provides.

Comment: @Crazed oh i didnt catch that sorry! Its still not 100%, but a little closer than. I still wouldnt recommend marking as accepted till its tried

Comment: @Crazed I posted another question and was wondering If you could answer it?

Comment: Ok, ill take a look at it

Comment: so, my mom has a internet thing that shuts down the internet and she blocked Minecraft that's why I couldn't access servers. lol